# How to make a post call using forms in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have an API-1 which is a get request, Now I have to make a POST request to API-2 with the body as response of API-1.I have to use forms to achieve this,as i cannot make an ajax call as CORS is blocked for that API. API1Callback  is the callback method for API-1

```
 API1Callback =(json) => {

    let url = json.BaseURL;
    <form id="myform" method="post" action={url} name ="myform">
            <input type="hidden" name="AccountID" value={json.AccountID}/>
            <input type="hidden" name="Amount" value={json.Amount}/>
            <input type="hidden" name="ProductID" value={json.ProductID}/>
            <input type="hidden" name="ProductName" value={json.ProductName}/>
          </form>
          document.getElementById("myform").submit();

    }
```

However this does not work, post request is not made.

Comment: I think this post will give you some idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53731604/9598077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use React-ref to solve this problem

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


class SDPRedirectInterstitialSF extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
     this.formElement=React.createRef();
    }

  render() {
    return(
            <form ref={this.formElement} action="http://payment/do" method="post" >
            <input type="hidden" name="AccountID" value={this.props.json.AccountID}/>
            <input type="hidden" name="SiteID" value={this.props.json.SiteID}/>

          <input type="hidden" name="Amount" value={this.props.json.Amount}/>

            <input type="hidden" name="ProductID" value={this.props.json.ProductID}/>
           <input type="hidden" name="ProductName" value={this.props.json.ProductName}/>

           </form>
       );
 }

  componentDidMount() 
  {
    this.formElement.current.submit();
  }
}

+export default SDPRedirectInterstitialSF
```