# In React how do you check if at least one checkbox has been selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I wrote a `Checkbox` component, with `React`, that is reused to generate a list of checkboxes. I know that a react element is different from a `DOM` in terms of state. But how do I check if at least 1 checkbox has been selected by the user on form submit in `React`?

I have searched in SO and Google but all examples are either in jQuery or vanilla JS. For my case I want a `React` example.

#### component

```js
const Checkbox = ({ title, options, id, name, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className="checkbox-group">
      <h4>{title}</h4>
      {options.map(option => (
        <label htmlFor={`${name}-${index}`} key={`${name}-${index}`}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name={name}
            value={option}
            onChange={onChange}
            id={`${name}-${index}`}
          />
          <span> {option}</span>
        </label>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
class Form extends Component {

  ...

  handleChange(event) {
    let newSelection = event.target.value;
    let newSelectionArray;

    newSelectionArray = [
      ...this.state.sureveyResponses.newAnswers,
      newSelection,
    ];

    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        surveyResponse: {
          ...this.state.surveyResponse,
          newAnswers: newSelectionArray,
      }
    )
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    // I'm guessing this doesn't work in React as it's using its own state!
    let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[name="quiz-0"]:checked');

    for (let chk in checkboxes) {
      if (chk.checked) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    alert('Please choose at least one answer.');
    return false;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <h4>Choose</>
        {this.state.surveyQuiz.map((quiz, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <Checkbox
                title={quiz.question}
                options={quiz.answers}
                name={`quiz-${index + 1}`}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })};
        <button>Save answer(s)</span>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

When the user submits the form, it should check if at least a checkbox is checked, if not none is checked then prevent the form to submit, i.e. return false!

Comment: The checkboxes should [precisely reflect an array of booleans in your state](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components); do that, and checking the checkboxes is as easy as calling `.some(...)` on the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also maintain the `checked` property in `surveyResponse.newAnswers` state. Then, you'll be able to check if any of them is `true`. For eg.:

```
const nA = this.state.surveyResponse.newAnswers
const isChecked = nA.some(c => c.checked == true)

if(isChecked) {
  //...if any of them has checked state
}
```

Assuming example `newAnswers` data:

```
[
  {answer:'foo', checked: false},
  {answer:'bar', checked: true},
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how to change your handleSubmit to read form data:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = event.target;
    const data = new FormData(form);
    for (let name of data.keys()) {
      const input = form.elements[name];
      console.log(input);
      console.log('value:', input.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! But this is not using React, I've tried using vanilla JS and it doesn't even get the generated element from React. Are you sure this is gonna work?

Comment: I don't understand why this received a negative point without being tested! Yes, this works and here is a working example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53731604/9598077

Comment: @Saosey2018 Off course I prefer to handle this in state and don't loop through the form elements but this can come handy in situations where there is no need to keep things in state.